# How to get Android Installed App Icon in Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Quickly, I want to get all the installed apps in the device (icon and label). I'm using a simple code that works getting the name of the app.

I use Android Java Class to get these informations. The problem is that Android optains app icon as a `Drawable`. Unity cannot read and display it as `Sprite`.

I am wondering if there is a way to sort this issue out. I have tried to encode the drawable to base64 string but Unity "replies" me with a "Invalid string length" error, maybe for the "infinite" length of the base64 string.

I am trying to convert the Drawable to a byte array and then use it to create a texture with `Texture.loadImage(byte[])` but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
 AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    int flag = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.pm.PackageManager").GetStatic<int>("GET_META_DATA");
    AndroidJavaObject pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    AndroidJavaObject packages = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstalledApplications", flag);

    int count = packages.Call<int>("size");
    string[] names = new string[count];
    int ii =0;
    for(int i=0; ii<count;){
            //get the object
        AndroidJavaObject currentObject = packages.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("get", ii );
        try{
                //try to add the variables to the next entry
            names[i] = pm.Call<string>("getApplicationLabel", currentObject);
            AndroidJavaObject icon = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationIcon", currentObject);//this part is the Java (Android Studio) code using Android Java Object and Class of Unity. Maybe the error is from here
            AndroidJavaObject bitmap = icon.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getBitmap");
            AndroidJavaClass stream = new AndroidJavaClass("java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
            bitmap.Call("compress",(new AndroidJavaClass("java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream")).Call<AndroidJavaObject>("JPEG"), 100, stream);
            byte[] bitMapData = stream.Call<byte[]>("toByteArray");//to here
            Texture2D mytexture = new Texture2D(50, 50); // no idea what default size would be?? is it important??
            if (!mytexture.LoadImage(bitMapData)) {
                Debug.Log("Failed loading image data!");
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("LoadImage - Still sane here - size: " + mytexture.width + "x" + mytexture.height);
                GameObject app = (GameObject)Instantiate(App, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
                app.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = mytexture;//here is the code should display the icon as texture (sprite would be the best)
            }
            i++;
            ii++;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.LogError(e,this);
                //if it fails, just go to the next app and try to add to that same entry.
            ii++;
        }

    }
```

Here there is the Java Android Studio working code:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) item.getIcon()).getBitmap(); //item.getIcon() returns the Drawable correctly
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I don't do Android development but couldn't you get the bitmap, get the pixels from the bitmap, and use those pixels to create a Texture in Unity? Why go through this buffer conversion?

Comment: The reason is that there is no way to do it with Unity, I have to use Android Java Class to get the bitmap and I don't know how to invoke Java code properly from Unity.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that Unity doesn't natively have equivalent to your above Java functionality. In that case you can write your code in Java to get your raw Color values and call that function with [AndroidJavaObject.Call](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an Android Jar Plugin on Android Studio (No Activity) and then I have imported it in Unity3D (AndroidManifest.xml and classes.jar in Assets>Plugins>Android>libs). Inside the plugin I have added a class and then the void to get the byte[] of the icon. Java Android Plugin Class:

```
public class PluginClass {

public static byte[] getIcon(PackageManager pm, ApplicationInfo applicationInfo) {
    try {
        BitmapDrawable icon = (BitmapDrawable) pm.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo);
        Bitmap bmp = icon.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean isSystem(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo){
    return (applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM ) != 0;
   }
}
Then I have invoked it in Unity C# script:

void Start () {
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    int flag = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.pm.PackageManager").GetStatic<int>("GET_META_DATA");
    AndroidJavaObject pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    AndroidJavaObject packages = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstalledApplications", 0);
    int count = packages.Call<int>("size");
    string[] names = new string[count];
    List<byte[]> byteimg = new List<byte[]>();
    int ii =0;
    for(int i=0; ii<count;){
        AndroidJavaObject currentObject = packages.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("get", ii );
        try{
            names[i] = pm.Call<string>("getApplicationLabel", currentObject);
            var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mypackagename.PluginClass");
            if(plugin.CallStatic<bool>("isSystem",currentObject)){
                ii++;
                continue;
            }
            byte[] decodedBytes = plugin.CallStatic<byte[]>("getIcon", pm, currentObject);
            Texture2D text = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
            text.LoadImage(decodedBytes);
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create (text, new Rect(0,0,text.width,text.height), new Vector2(.5f,.5f));
            i++;
            ii++;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Debug.LogError(e,this);
            ii++;
        }

    }
```